# Blender, changing Pose of character changes already made animations

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, pose-mode, nla-editor

I have a cow model that, in its Rest Position, is standing up normally on its 4 legs. Then, i also have the cow in Pose Position, in which the cow is siting. My current 4 animations of this cow are with the Cow sitting, shes either waving or looking around etc. Now i wanted to make other types of animations such as running, but the problem starts when i reset the pose with ALT-G and ALT-R, it resets the cow to its rest position as it should (standing up on its 4 legs), but now all my animations have changed aswell. It seems that the animations are referencing the cow in its Pose Position. How can i simply change the cow's position to whatever i desire without breaking all my animations so i can make other types of animations?

Comment: Did you miss keyframing some bones? Might help to add  images or blend file.

Comment: ah that might be the problem, for example when i create one animation, my first keyframe i add all channels (all bones), but for the next keyframes, i only add the rotation and location of one particular bone (the head for example, to simply rotate the head left and right, since i'm not gonna need all bones for this) and then the final keyframe has all channels again. Should I add all channels for every keyframe? isn't that a bit "overhead" or computacional expensive once it goes to the game engine?

Comment: Actually let me update on that, what i think i should do is the following:
1st keyframe: commit All bones with all channels;; 
2nd keyframe: commit All bones, but only necessary channels (if i only rotate the head, then commit all bones with Rotation only) ;;
3rd, 4th, 5th..etc keyframes: do the same as the 2nd keyframe ;;
last keyframe: commit All bones and all channels.

Comment: Final update haha: actually i didnt have to do any of what i said previously, basically what i did was all channels all bones in First and Last keyframe, and then the middle keyframes just use the necessary bones. This is what i tought i had in the first place but apparently i didnt. so it's fixed :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Consider looking into the auto-key feature (looks like a record button in the Timeline window). It sets keyframes automatically.